# Not able to Generate SHA Keys in Android Studio 'setlocalset' is not recognized

Tags: android, android-app-signing

PS C:\Users\rmk\Desktop\eCart Customer v5.0.1> .\gradlew signingReport
'setlocalset' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the batch label specified - findJavaFromJavaHomeset

PS C:\Users\rmk\Desktop\eCart Customer v5.0.1> java -version
java version "18.0.2.1" 2022-08-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2.1+1-1)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2.1+1-1, mixed mode, sharing)

### When i tried with gradle signingReport , it was generating key for debug , not for release
Variant: release
Config: null
Store: null
Alias: null

Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\rmk.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: 95:33:5C:47:31:61:0F:E3:E6:8C:1B:EC:23:D8:42:CE
SHA1: 5F:DC:05:B6:E3:0A:C5:C0:D3:D0:95:D3:32:49:15:8A:71:45:4C:89
SHA-256: 3D:D1:07:12:9D:D4:F9:35:3A:66:11:9F:31:38:BC:D8:34:9E:AF:6B:52:1D:93:D9:EC:85:1D:CA:23:0E:33:51
Valid until: Monday, 20 January, 2053

Answer (score 0):

For getting the release variant sha, you will need to create a signing key first as follows using android:-

1. Open the Android Studio project for which you want to create a signing key.
2. Click on the "Build" menu and select "Generate Signed Bundle / APK".
3. In the "Generate Signed Bundle or APK" dialog box, select "APK" as the destination and then click on the "Create new" button next to the key store path.
4. Fill in the required fields, such as the key store and key aliases, and set a password for the key.
5. Click on the "OK" button to generate the signing key.
6. After the signing key is created, you can use it to sign and export your Android app as a signed bundle or APK.

Note: This process is to create a key for signing the APK and it should be kept safe as it is needed for every update you make on the app.